# Google Play Game Services Real-time Multiplayer stopped working

Tags: google-play-games

There was a global issue with Google Play games services. Since March 28, about half of users do not work online multiplayer. I get a lot of emails from users. The problem is really global. With her faced many developers. This may be due to the Google services update on users ' devices. This may be a regional problem. I am in Minsk (Belarus), however through vpn Germany at me earned. I apologize for my English.

> onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) method throws an error:
>   statusCode 4

Other references describing the problem:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/play/dP3BHrI1vN4/CB_pwgHlCQAJ

[Google Play Service Real-Time Multiplayer is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587007/google-play-service-real-time-multiplayer-is-broken)

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2163

Comment: What is the question here? It hard to tell in current format of question..

Comment: I hope to get an answer from google games services support.

Comment: This is a known issue on the Google side. Our engineers are working to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 6):

What I have found about this problem:

I have created simple android game with google play games service. When I test my game multiplayer works fine, I can create quick game or invite friends.

But the last few days I can not initialize multiplayer. I always get this error:

```
Error: onRoomCreated, status 4
```

Status 4: A network error occurred while attempting to retrieve fresh data, and no data was available locally.

Ok, I switch off the Real-time multiplayer in developer console and now error became:

```
Error: onRoomCreated, status 6003
```

Status 6003: This game does not support multiplayer.

This means that all my game Client ID and tester account are setting correct and error happens with network connection.

I created new game in game service developer console and connected another android app with different app id, but get the same status 4 error.

I try to remove Play Game and Play Market apps cash data and reinstall all it updates. Error is the same.

I try to unlock in-game achievements and it UNLOCKED correct and show them in game description in Google Play Game app.

I downloaded several apps from play store, and get Play Games service error while creating online game. I read app reviews and some people write about this error.

I create VPN connection and try to init multiplayer and all works fine! Game room is created without any error!

What I have found:

If I try to init multiplayer without VPN tunnel there is SSL error in logcat

```
I/libjingle: BeginSSL: talk.google.com
W/libjingle: Warning(openssladapter.cc:388): ContinueSSL -- error 0
W/libjingle: Warning(openssladapter.cc:397): OpenSSLAdapter::Error(ContinueSSL, -1)
I/libjingle: SSL Cleanup
Error: onRoomCreated, status 4
```

With VPN tunnel SSL connection start normally, provide connection information and multiplayer game works.

I am from Russia.

Testing devices:

Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, Google Play Games (5.5.81), Play Market (9.3.14-all)

Nexus 5X, Android 8.1.0, Google Play Games (5.5.81), Play Market (9.4.18-all)

Device factory reset also did not help.

In my build.gradle:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:12.0.1"
```

and 11.8.0 version is not working too.

This problem happens not only with mobile network internet, with wired internet (through wifi connection) it does not work too.

I create VPN tunnel using Turbo VPN android app, and multiplayer works, but not with all countries, for example if I create VPN through US and Netherlands multiplayer works, through UK and Germany not.

And the **most important** thing is that it's been 7 days, but **Google has not done anything**!

Link to google issue tracker: [Google Play Multyplayer Not Work!! (issue 77501859)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77501859)